# Magento login not working properly with FPC

Tags: magento-1.9, full-page-cache, customer-session

I have a block on the header with welcome message and user name to show only if a user logged in . I'm using lesti fpc extension when fpc enabled and logged into a customer account and go back to home page but message block on the header is not showing as I'm logged in. but in some inner pages and it will also disappear if I refresh a page several times .

How can I solve this issue? do I have hole punch this block if yes how to do it as it involve sessions ?

Comment: If you are using Magento 1.7 or lower: https://gordonlesti.com/lestifpc-magento-1-7-and-the-welcome-message/

Comment: @B00MER but I'm using magento 1.9.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Aoe_TemplateHints](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints) and utilize it to identify the block names and the cache status.  After this you can specify in the configuration of the Lesti_FPC module to not cache the block in question.

More than likely the welcome block differs from the name that is standard `welcome` put the new block name in the lazy blocks area of the configuration in the admin:

- https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc/blob/master/app/code/community/Lesti/Fpc/etc/config.xml#L230

How Lesti_FPC works:

- https://gordonlesti.com/how-does-lesti-fpc-work/

Comment: I have removed the default block and loaded it using ajax after the page load so it seems solved the issue , but still there is a small delay of initiating the ajax, So I will also try your method :)

Comment: Cool, glad to hear.  Normally this block should be automatically hole punched for you with the lestiFPC module.